# Can Arduino UNO R3 act as both keyboard/mouse at same time?

Tags: arduino, firmware, hid

I know that the UNO R3 can be flashed with FLIP to enumerate as a keyboard OR a mouse. I've successfully done this.

My question here is, are there any methods that allow it to perform like the Leonardo in the respect that it can **send raw mouse/keyboard commands at the same time**? Rather than requiring special firmware for one or the other?

I currently have a a piece of software just decoding serial communication from the Arduino, and sending strokes/movements to Windows... but it's far from what is desired. Mostly because a lot application and games will restrict the keyboard strokes from being automated....

So, is there any possible way to do this type of solution? Or am I stuck with:

> 1. Buy a better board
> 2. Build better keyboard spoofing software

Comment: Just FYI. There is now a stack dedicated to Arduino http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: What you want is a USB Composite Device, consisting of a USB HID Mouse and USB HID Keyboard. For the most part, a USB HID mouse and keyboard use almost exactly the same setups. Only problem is the memory available on your microcontroller. You might want to look at the actual firmware to see the difference, which is quite minimal.